# Is there a way to create a key on and remove duplicates when they happen?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a unique combokey on Site and ASIN and remove duplicates while creating

so far I have
ALTER TABLE Products ADD UNIQUE (Site,ASIN)
I figure there needs to be an "On Duplicate" but I cant find the right thing to do within http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html .. does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Does the table have other columns such that a `SELECT DISTINCT *` would still return duplicates for `(Site,ASIN)`?

Comment: It does, the current UNIQUE key is on 4 columns

Comment: ALTER IGNORE TABLE ? does anyone know the affect this would have?

Comment: When you have a UNIQUE KEY mysql throws and exception when you try to insert duplicates. What do you mean by removing duplicates when they happen?

Comment: Instead of throwing the error, it just deletes the duplicate on key creation

Comment: you mean there are already duplicate values and you cannot create the unique key and you want to force create it and at the same time remove the duplicates? am i understanding it right?

Comment: if so, what is your criteria to choose a record from the duplicate ones? let's say you have 4 records that have the same Site and ASIN. Which 3 do you want to remove?

Comment: I want to keep the one with the most non empty columns

Comment: ex, I want to keep one that has ASIN, EAN,UPC,SKU over ASIN, EAN,UPC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is such a thing as `ON DUPLICATE` when adding a `UNIQUE KEY`. So you need to find a workaround. Here is a suggestion:

1- Identify the duplicate rows and store the values in a temp table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Duplicates 
  (SELECT
     Site, ASIN
   FROM
     Products
   GROUP BY
     Site, ASIN
   HAVING
     COUNT(*) > 1
   );
```

2- join the temp table with the original table and delete the duplicate rows that you don't need anymore. (from the comments I think you want to remove the ones with SKU IS NULL)

```
DELETE p 
FROM 
  Products AS p 
INNER JOIN 
  Duplicates AS d 
ON 
  d.Site = p.Site and d.ASIN = p.ASIN
WHERE
  p.SKU IS NULL;
```

3- create your unique key:

```
ALTER TABLE Products ADD UNIQUE KEY (Site, ASIN);
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8bb7c/1/0) I created.

Comment: Ended up running the unique key insert above and just re running crawlers... but this works too.